# Sample size for a research paper (for Mean+SD type of data)

Tags: mean, sample-size, standard-error, real-time

In my research paper I proposed a software and have experiment it on 72 users. But the reviewer has objected on the sample size and asked to justify it or increase it.  below is the results of our experiment:

[image]

My question is that how much sample size would be ok for this type of data.

Please note that because the region/university where the research was conducted , people are only using Windows OS, but the software that we have developed is based on Linux. So we had mostly short listed those users whose computer usage experience is above 10 years and level of experience is of Expert level. So that they face no/least issue in using the software in Linux environment.

thanks.

Comment: Hi, welcome. For starters, please provide a full citation of the objection. Secondly, what are you trying to detect statistically? What was your research hypothesis and how does that relate to this data? – *Reviewer* ;)

Comment: @jim thanks. the table shows my whole experiment. In this i compare three software system on the basis of time and steps (human effort). I compare that how much time and steps (human effort) each software system takes to retrieve files. 
  

Reviewer's 1 objection: More experiment needs to be conducted and the sample size used must be increased in order to firmly generalize the findings.
 
Reviewer's 2 objection: the number of participants seem small. The authors need to justify whether the size chosen is suitable in order to consider the results findings significant

Answer (score 3):

Without an answer to the questions in @Jim's comment it is difficult to give answers that I'm sure will be useful.

My guess is that you have three software
programs and you are trying to see if they have significantly different
running times.
If that is the case, it would be possible to use a one-factor ANOVA with three levels of the factor. The number of replications (unclear whether that is number of files or number of users) you would need in order to have reasonable power (probability of detecting real differences, if they exist) depends on the standard deviation of the running times and the size of the differences you want to detect.

So you will know the kinds of computations that can be done, I will show some
graphs that show powers for various differences among means assuming (1) a significance level of 5%, (b) a standard deviation of 8 sec, and sample sizes of 130, 150, and 200 for each type of software.

[image]

A difficulty with your
data is that the standard deviations of the three kinds of software seem to
have very different standard deviations. The results in the figure are for a kind of ANOVA that assumes equal standard deviations (SDs) for each type of software. There are alternate ANOVA procedures that can accommodate different SDs, but the their power would be somewhat different from what the figure shows.

As you can see, power increases with sample size, but for detecting differences as large as 3 or more seconds, the sample sizes I used to make the figure give
power above 0.8, which many researchers think is OK. But if you need to 
detect differences as small as 1 or 2 seconds, you would need larger sample sizes.

I have guessed your objectives and that this is the kind of information you need,
If I have guessed correctly, then we are started on the right track. If the general idea is on target, but the numbers need to be changed, that is easy enough to do.

If this is not at all what you need, maybe you can use this as a starting point to modify your question so we can move toward more useful answers.

*Note:* The figure above is from Minitab 17; other statistical software can make similar figures.